# SimpleEllipseExample just does not work in Piccolo2D?

Tags: java, piccolo

What piccolo example below should actually do? I draws nothing for me. And paint method never called:

```
package test.piccolo;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

import edu.umd.cs.piccolo.PNode;
import edu.umd.cs.piccolo.nodes.PText;
import edu.umd.cs.piccolo.util.PPaintContext;
import edu.umd.cs.piccolox.PFrame;

public class SimpleEllipseNode extends PNode {
    private Ellipse2D ellipse;

    // This nodes uses an internal Ellipse2D to define its shape.
    public Ellipse2D getEllipse() {
        if (ellipse == null)
            ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double();
        return ellipse;
    }

    // This method is important to override so that the geometry of
    // the ellipse stays consistent with the bounds geometry.
    public boolean setBounds(double x, double y, double width, double height) {
        if (super.setBounds(x, y, width, height)) {
            ellipse.setFrame(x, y, width, height);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // Non rectangular subclasses need to override this method so
    // that they will be picked correctly and will receive the
    // correct mouse events.
    public boolean intersects(Rectangle2D aBounds) {
        return getEllipse().intersects(aBounds);
    }

    // Nodes that override the visual representation of their super
    // class need to override a paint method.
    public void paint(PPaintContext aPaintContext) {
        Graphics2D g2 = aPaintContext.getGraphics();
        g2.setPaint(getPaint());
        g2.fill(getEllipse());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PFrame frame = new PFrame() {

            @Override
            public void initialize() {

                PNode aNode = new SimpleEllipseNode();
                //PNode aNode = new PText("Hello World!");

                // Add the node to the canvas layer so that it
                // will be displayed on the screen.
                getCanvas().getLayer().addChild(aNode);
            }

        };

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ellipse is not painted probably because the bounds of `SimpleEllipseNode` are empty. Add these lines to `initialize()` :

```
aNode.setPaint(Color.RED);
aNode.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100);
```

And it should paint a red ellipse. There is an NPE in `setBounds()` since the `ellipse` is not initialized yet. This can be fixed by adding `getEllipse();` as a first line in `setBounds()`.

Not sure what is the reason behind overriding `paint()` and `setBounds()`, as usually you can get away easily by using compositional nodes. For example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import edu.umd.cs.piccolo.nodes.PPath;
import edu.umd.cs.piccolox.PFrame;

public class SimpleEllipseNode {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        PFrame frame = new PFrame() {
            @Override
            public void initialize() {
                final PPath circle = PPath.createEllipse(0, 0, 100, 100);
                circle.setPaint(Color.RED);
                getCanvas().getLayer().addChild(circle);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How can it happen that a sample is so buggy?

Comment: You're welcome! Not sure where this sample came from, may be it is not complete or intentions were different. Take a look at [Piccolo2D Patterns](http://www.piccolo2d.org/learn/patterns.html), it has lots of examples. Also, the best examples are in Piccolo's source tree in `edu.umd.cs.piccolo.examples` package.